# Function pointer to non-static function

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

I'm trying to make an array of function pointers to alleviate some code that would otherwise be nightmarish. I want to use a set of functions like the one that follows.

```
void drawNothing(Point2, Point2, Point2, Point2);
```

I have defined a type for the function pointers.

```
typedef void(*FunctionPointer)(Point2, Point2, Point2, Point2);
```

And an array to store the pointers themselves.

```
FunctionPointer drawMSCase[16];
```

The problem is that when I try to assign a function to one of the slots, like so

```
drawMSCase[0] = &Grid::drawNothing;
```

I get the following error

```
 error: cannot convert 'void (Grid::*)(Point2, Point2, Point2, Point2)' to 'Grid::FunctionPointer {aka void (*)(Point2, Point2, Point2, Point2)}' in assignment
```

It works if I define the function as static, but I can't really do that for it would have too big an impact on my design. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer thanks to the suggestions that SO shows to the right.

Given that I wanted to use pointers to member functions of class Grid, I had to specify that in the typedef declaration.

```
typedef void(Grid::*FunctionPointer)(Point2, Point2, Point2, Point2);
```

Notice the **Grid::** which was missing before.

Comment: Thats' great. Just keep in mind that "indicating the class" is not just a piece of cosmetic syntax. Such pointer is a beast of completely different nature from ordinary function pointer. The two are not interchangeable and not compatible. Hopefully, you do not need them to be.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer to make it more informative.